# Get Coordinates before and after touch released

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, libgdx

I am trying to make slingshot type thing(like in angry birds) using LIBGDX(currently learning). So, how do I get the coordinates of the point where user touched the screen and dragged finger to other point n released . I want both co-ordinates initial and released point.

I also want to know how to achieve the above in Android SDK/NDK.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this but this should be around about what you need

```
@Override
Public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
int downx;
int downy;
int upx;
int upy;
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       downy = (int)event.gety();
       downx = (int)event.getx();
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
         upy = (int)event.gety();
         upx = (int)event.getx();
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: the ints could have class wide scope so you can change them from inside the method

Comment: this one is for native android?

Comment: I haven't done android in a year or 2 but from memory this should work

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TempScreen extends Screen
{

Game game; // the class which is implementing the InputProcessor
SpriteBatch batcher;
Vector3 touchPoint;
OrthographicCamera cam;
InputMultiplexer multiplexer;
GestureListener listener=new GestureListener()
{

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
    {
        cam.unproject(touchPoint.set(x, y, 0));
        System.out.println(touchPoint);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2,
            Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
};

GestureDetector detector=new GestureDetector(listener)
{
    public boolean touchUp(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) 
    {
        cam.unproject(touchPoint.set(x, y, 0));
        System.out.println(touchPoint);

        return false;
    }
};
public TempScreen(Game game,SpriteBatch batcher)
{
    super(game);
    this.batcher=batcher;
    this.game=game;
    touchPoint = new Vector3();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(GameConstants.CAMERA_WIDTH,GameConstants.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    cam.position.set(GameConstants.CAMERA_WIDTH / 2,GameConstants.CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    multiplexer.addProcessor(game);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(detector);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

}

@Override
public void render(float deltaTime)
{
    update(deltaTime);
    GLCommon gl = Gdx.gl;
    gl.glClearColor(0, 0f, 1f, 0.1f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batcher.enableBlending();
    batcher.begin();
    draw(deltaTime);
    batcher.end();
}

@Override
public void draw(float deltaTime)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void backKeyPressed()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: sent you the customized code for you it it work for you do lety me know i will edit my answer here

Answer (score 0):

Make an InputProcessor and a Vector3:

```
MyInputprocessor myInputprocessor;
Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3();
```

Define the InputProcessor like this:

```
public class MyInputprocessor implements InputProcessor{

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
        guicam.unproject(touchPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0)); //Initial point coordinates
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer){
        guicam.unproject(touchPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0)); //current point coordinates (when you are dragging it)
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
        guicam.unproject(touchPoint.set(screenX, screenY, 0)); //final/release point coordinates
        return false;
    }

    @Override public boolean keyTyped(char character){return false;}
    @Override public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY){return false;}
    @Override public boolean scrolled(int amount){return false;}
    @Override public boolean keyDown(int keycode){return false;}
    @Override public boolean keyUp(int keycode){return false;}
}
```

Create it and set it in your ini code:

```
myInputprocessor = new MyInputprocessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myInputprocessor);
```